# Google Play Services Sync problem on Android 2.3.6

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-play-services

I have a phone Samsung **GT-S5302** it has **stock ROM** and **root**.

---

When it connects to internet it started to sync as always (sync icon appears), but the icon doesn't disappear even after 8 hours and I can't enter Google Play Store, Google+ account, Hangouts, I get an error "Google Talk authentication problem" and it reduces all phone performance.

Then I try to freeze Google Play Services with Link2SD problem disappear: sync works fine, error disappear, I can enter to Android Play Market, download and install app...
But in this case Google+, Hangouts of course don't work because they need Google Play Services to work fine.

### What I've already tried:

- I tried to erase cash, app data of the next processes: Play Market, Google Play Services, Google Services Framework and reboot device.
- I tried to erase userdata and add only my google account again with no changes.
- I tried to reinstall gapps for gingerbread using CWM unsuccessfully again.
- I tried to switch off automatic date/time settings and after reboot turn on again - no luck.
- I tried to delete Google Play Services and reinstall it with Play Market - the same problem.

---

So the question is:
Is there any way to solve the problem with Google+ or may be one know where do I need to look or what do I need to do further?

Comment: Have you tried restoring factory settings? Is the problem new?

Comment: After restoring factory settings, adding Google account and launch Google Play Market I get the same problem: Google play market download Google Play services and it try to sync something. So as I understand it is not because of my installed applications (they are absent) or root privileges (I removed root but it doesn't help). I start to think nowadays that it is because of mobile hardware that can't work properly with new versions of Google Play Services.

Comment: Maybe if you look at the log it might lead you somewhere. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through verbose log of my mobile phone I noticed that Google Play Services (GMS) can't find class "android.os.UserManager" and it has another dead codes connected with Google Play Services (gms).

[image]

And this blocks of errors apear over and over again so Google Play Services restarts them self. Class "android.os.UserManager" require API level 17; my phone has API level 10 so I decided to install the older versions of Goolge Play Services. 
After that I find out that problems appear with versions of Goolge Play Services greater then 8.3.0. With 8.3.0 and below there is no such problem. Google+ works fine with this version of GMS.

I install all programs that I need using Play Market and after that I delete all data and updates of Play Market to prevent updating Goolge Play Services (I find out that Play Market respones for updating Goolge Play Services).

Answer (score -1):

I too had this problem. I think you too have noticed that the *Google Play Services* app crashes as well. So I firstly uninstalled it.

Then after rooting my phone, I factory-resetted everything (lot o f times) and after that, now it works smoothly. And no problem in synchronization either.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please don't use "txtspeak" / "SMS lingo" on SE sites, but rather fully spell each word. Many users here are no native English speakers, and some already have a hard enough time to follow normal English.

Comment: I don't think suggested variant might help me. Because I tried even to format data, system, cache partitions using CWM and after that I flash stock ROM using Odin. And this doesn,t help.